# SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on Ubuntu 18.05 Linux seems to only use one processor

Tags: linux, sql-server-2019

I set up this db on an old server that has Ubuntu 18.04 in order to test some new features of SQL Server 2019.  First time running SQL Server on Linux.  I am running an intense query and happened to pull up htop on the Linux machine and noticed that only one processor was reaching 100% while the 24 others were showing idle.

I was under the impression that the developer version would use all available cores and that this was abstracted away.  Am I mistaken in believing developer should use all available processors or am I missing a setting here?

Comment: Not all queries can go parallel. Just because there are extra cores to use does not mean they can be used. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134453/sql-not-engaging-parallelism-for-extremely-large-query

Comment: Hi Nick, is it possible to add the query you are referring to to the question? What are  your maxdop and ctfp settings set to?