# Part of parallel execution plan has serial portion

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, parallelism, functions, query-performance

I have a big linq to sql query which runs in parallel mode.
It is returning results in 8 seconds and it is pretty good.
I noticed in the execution plan that the extreme right part(from where execution plan is read) of the execution plan has a serial portion.
I checked the execution plan and i see that the serial part is calculating some expressions such as the where conditions `Start Date` and `End date` is applied and calculated.
But i don't understand why it is being in serial mode.
AS per the screenshot,it says `Scalar Operators[Expr1169]` and `Scalar Operator(Expr1170)`

As you can see in the next screenshot, after the expressions are calculated and after from `Nested Loops` ,the execution goes into Parallel mode.
I am trying to understand the serial part of the query ,because i have optimized the query few times to strictly run in parallel mode.
I have removed some scalar functions earlier and other db objects which can cause serial execution.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTDq.png)
[image]

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFTDq.png)
[image]
Please find the anonymized execution plan.
[Execution PLan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryaHrYXWH)

Additional Info:

- Statistics are updated
- Index Fragmentation is taken care off
- 96 GB out of 128GB is used by SQL Server.
- SQL Server 2016

Statistics are updated.

Comment: Can you add the query? Looks like you have a case statement wrapped in isnull.

Comment: Actually the query is pulling from a view which has like 10 tables joins and these CASE statements exists in the view.Yes there is case statement wrapped in IS NULL in the view.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question being asked (why is this portion of the query serial), I would ask another question: what would you gain from that part of the query being parallel?

Zooming in a little on one of the small serial portions of the plan that you mentioned:

[image: screenshot of plan explorer, zoomed in on the serial portion of the query]

There is only one row coming out of the "Merge Interval" operator.  Having that one row flow in to a parallel nested loops join would result in essentially the same behavior as the current plan: a serial nested loops join (with the added negative repercussion of there being unnecessary [thread reservations](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/10/sql-plan/parallel-plans-branches-threads)).

There will be at most 2 rows coming out of the "Merge Interval" operator, depending on the specific values of the parameters being used in the query (manifested as the separate "Constant Scan" operators see [this question and answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/can-you-explain-this-execution-plan) for a general explanation of what's going on there).  In the 2-row scenario, you're still unlikely to get a lot of benefit from parallelism here.

Overall: even if you were able to manage to get the NL join to be parallel, it doesn't seem like it would help you very much.

---

For a more general treatment of why parallelism might be inhibited in portions of a query plan, or the entire thing, see [SQL not engaging parallelism for extremely large query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134453/sql-not-engaging-parallelism-for-extremely-large-query).

Comment: I am trying to fix possible issues as i am not sure what is the reach cause.

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to fix then? This seems like an X Y problem.